# How to get just one result when using MAX and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I would love some help on this query:

```
select *
from STORAGE_MOVEMENT 
where  object_id = 43500 and current_location != 6411 and object_class = 'SAMPLE'
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

I'm trying to fetch only the result with the biggest `move_number` of these two. With a `MAX(move_number)` it would work, but I also need other information, specifically the data in the `Moved_On` column.

I'm trying to make it work with this query but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT MAX(move_number), object_id, original_location, current_location, moved_on   
FROM    
    (SELECT *
     FROM STORAGE_MOVEMENT 
     WHERE object_id = 43500 AND current_location != 6411 AND object_class = 'SAMPLE'
     ) A
GROUP BY 
    object_id, original_location, current_location, moved_on
```

But this shows basically the same result as the previous query :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Really? What message does it show to you?

Comment: When using `Group by`, it finds rows which have the same values for all the columns you have specified, then makes those into one row. In your case,  only `object_id` seems to be the same across both rows; the other fields are different (and therefore become separate rows in the group by).

Comment: *"What message does it show to you?"* we can't run that query, @dontknowcoding, we don't have access to your instance, however, I can clearly see a `GROUP BY` clause in your sub query, which uses `SELECT *` (so no aggregation functions) and the table clearly has more than one column, due to the `WHERE` referencing other columns. So you're going to get an error along the lines of "`Column 'object_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want top(1)

```
 SELECT top(1) *
 FROM STORAGE_MOVEMENT 
 WHERE object_id = 43500 AND current_location != 6411 AND object_class = 'SAMPLE'
 ORDER BY move_number DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `row_number` function:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY move_number DESC) AS Row#, 
    object_id, original_location, current_location, moved_on   
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM STORAGE_MOVEMENT 
     WHERE object_id = 43500 AND current_location != 6411 AND object_class = 'SAMPLE'
     GROUP BY moved_on) A
WHERE 
    Row# = 1;
```

Comment: For some reason it won't work on mine. It shows me this error: "[SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Row'.  I changed you code to this, but it would be basically the same:                                               SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY move_number DESC) AS Row, object_id,original_location,current_location,moved_on
FROM (select * 
   from STORAGE_MOVEMENT 
   where object_id = 43500 and current_location != 6411 and object_class = 'SAMPLE')A 
WHERE Row = 1

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using additional columns along with max ().

You must limit the number of columns and perform a JOIN on the result with the rest.

Something like,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.maximu, b.object_id, b.original_location, b.current_location, b.moved_on FROM 
(SELECT MAX (move_number) as maximum, current_location) FROM STORAGE_MOVEMENT GROUP BY current_location) as a 
JOIN STORAGE_MOVEMENT as b ON a.current_location = b .current_location as b
```

You get the MAX value for move_number according to current_location and other values ​​that belong to current_location.

However, the data will be redundant, so you must use, for example, DISTINCT, or maybe add join maximum move_number values. Thus, a.maximum = b.move_number